# Using methods defined in a module with class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, helper

I have a small problem that I can't quite get my head around. Since I want to reuse a lot of the methods defined in my Class i decided to put them into an Helper, which I can easily include whenever needed. The basic Class looks like this:

```
class MyClass
  include Helper::MyHelper
  def self.do_something input
    helper_method(input)
  end
end
```

And here is the Helper:

```
  module Helper
    module MyHelper
      def helper_method input
        input.titleize
      end
    end
  end
```

Right now I can't call "helper_method" from my Class because of what I think is a scope issue? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should investigate difference between include and extend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is because `self` pointer inside of `do_something input` is `InternshipInputFormatter`, and not the instance of `InternshipInputFormatter`. so proper alias to call `helper_method(input)` will be `self.helper_method(input)`, however you have *included* the `Helper::MyHelper` into the `InternshipInputFormatter` class as an instance methods, not a singleton, so try to *extend* the class with the instance methods of the module as the signelton methods for the class:

```
class InternshipInputFormatter
   extend Helper::MyHelper
   def self.do_something input
      helper_method(input)
   end
end 

InternshipInputFormatter.do_something 1
# NoMethodError: undefined method `titleize' for 1:Fixnum
```

As you can see, the call has stopped the execution inside the `helper_method`. Please refer to the [document](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) to see the detailed difference between `include`, and `extend`.